# beginning java swing, giving buttons function

Tags: java, swing, function, button

I'm currently in a class that does a intro to swing. We were tasked with creating a calculator GUI. I made the GUI that was requested with a combination of border layout and Grid layout.
Im not sure how to give the buttons function though, went over lecture notes and see it no where.

I have seen examples online but all look the same and I dont think they help as the ones ive seen use a single button and I need a way to differentiate my buttons as each has its own operation.

TO NOTE
I dont need any function with this calculator I just need it to record button clicks, once I get this figured out I will be adding it to a String "input" and keeping that visual to the user. IE if a user (the teacher) hits 5 * 5 that needs to show up at the top of screen but I don't need the answer of 25.

this is my code, it runs and has the gui layout I want.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GUI extends JFrame implements ItemListener{ //ActionListener
    //JTextArea info = new JTextArea("this will calculate numbers");
    JTextField f1 = new JTextField(10); //param = width
    protected String input;

    //*****************************************************************************************************************




    //constructor
    //@ args String, Int, Int
    public GUI(String title, int width, int height ){
        //gui.pack() *try this later*

        setBounds(500, 170, width, height);// sets location x,y on screen at start of program also sets size of GUI x,y

        setTitle(title); //sets title of

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //needed else x wont close properly



        createGUI();

    }

    //separate gui logic from other logic
    public void createGUI(){

        //set layout you plan to use
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //add(info, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(f1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //CENTER********************************************************************************************************
        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        center.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
        center.add(new JButton("1"));
        center.add(new JButton("2"));
        center.add(new JButton("3"));
        center.add(new JButton("4"));
        center.add(new JButton("5"));
        center.add(new JButton("6"));
        center.add(new JButton("7"));
        center.add(new JButton("8"));
        center.add(new JButton("9"));
        center.add(new JButton("0"));
        center.add(new JButton("."));
        center.add(new JButton("C"));
        add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //EAST**********************************************************************************************************
        JPanel east = new JPanel();
        east.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));
        east.add(new JButton("+"));
        east.add(new JButton("-"));
        east.add(new JButton("x"));
        east.add(new JButton("/"));
        east.add(new JButton("%"));
        east.add(new JButton("="));
        add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }


    //main
    public static void main(String[] args){
        GUI calculator = new GUI("GUI Calculator",300,250);

        calculator.setVisible(true);//makes calculator gui visible *make this line last or close to last*

    }

    //Must do this method or else class must be made abstract
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have the time to [read some tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)?

Comment: *"the ones ive seen use a single button and I need a way to differentiate my buttons"* One way to do that is to use '[anonymous](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) [inner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) classes' for the buttons.  One for each button.

Comment: I dont think I included enough info, I think I understand about adding a action listener it must have one but how does the action listener differentiate buttons? It seems to me there must be a way to do like btn1.addActionListener(1) ...................btn2.addActionListener(2)  then              public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
                a switch here for event 1
    }

Comment: event 2... 3 etc but everyone and the examples ive seen only do for action listener e then do whatever which is fine for a single button or two if you use a boolean type but..... im just confused..... i know I need a and b to get to c I just dont see how a and b work no matter how many libraries I read or examples I see and im sure its simple... just not clicking...

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, for each button, you want to assign a `ActionListener` to it, which, when the user activates the button, will call it's `actionPerformed`, method.

Personally, I would use `Action`, which is a self continued unit of work, but you could use inner classes or anonymous classes, I would avoid using one large `actionPerformed` method, as it becomes difficult to manage over time

See [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks soo much for the answer, I managed to understand it finally after another mug of coffee and a 30 minute break. Thanks again m8 and have a great day/night!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ActionListener to buttons;)